# Working out the original height of scaled and rotated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

In the following example, I have five sections and a console log which prints out the current scroll position, the height of the section, and the position of the section in the document. When the sections have not been manipulated, on my screen, the results are the following.

```
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 10, Height Of Section: 196.796875
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 216.796875, Height Of Section: 196.796875
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 423.59375, Height Of Section: 196.796875
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 630.390625, Height Of Section: 196.796875
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 837.1875, Height Of Section: 196.796875
```

However, after the sections are manipulated the results read.

```
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 10, Height Of Section: 225.51136779785156
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 216.85635375976562, Height Of Section: 225.51138305664062
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 423.59375, Height Of Section: 225.5113525390625
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 630.4501342773438, Height Of Section: 225.5113525390625
Current Scroll Position: 0, Position Of Section: 837.1875, Height Of Section: 225.5113525390625
```

My question: Is there a way to get the height of the element, before the element was manipulated, after the element has been manipulated?

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/paajn0Ls/2/) for the unmanipulated sections and this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/paajn0Ls/3/) for the manipulated ones.

Comment: Dan, do you consider your new heights as the distance from the highest point at the left side and the lowest point at the right or every rectangle?

Comment: @JoelHernandez I consider the height as the top edge to the bottom edge of the unrotated element but I don't know how to tell the code that

Answer (score 0):

Dan, You can try setting a cookie for every height of the rectangles:

**Set a Cookie in JS:**

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Then, you could retrieve the value of the height after the rotation:

**Get a Cookie in JS:**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is one approach. Hope this helps!